# JPA : Mapping a OneToOne Long value (not an entity) to another tables column which is not a primary key

Tags: java, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

So I have an entity which has a one to one relationship to an existing database in the table. The field I want it mapped to is not a primary key, however.
How can I achieve this? What do I add to the below?

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Long otherTableField;
}
```

Comment: If join column value = PK of myEntity then you can try `@SecondaryTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify the `@JoinColumn` with `referencedColumnName`:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "other_table_non_primary_id", referencedColumnName= "non_primary_id"
private OtherTable otherTableField;
```

Also, the type has to be `OtherTable` not Long.

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to map out the other table which already exists in the database. Is it not possible to just map the Id as a Long?

Comment: This is not how JPA works. You can use long but it would be justt a @Basic column